# Detecting how hard someone is pushing the screen on wp7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, touch

I am trying to detect how hard someone is pushing the wp7 screen for a drawing application. Is there a way to detect how big surface area is where the screen is being touched. I reckon that would be a reasonably accurate way to determine how hard the screen is being touched - A light touch would have a small touch surface area while a hard press would have a bigger touch area.

Has anyone ever tried something like this?

Comment: Are you expecting all users to use their fingers? I don't think the idea of a harder touch == bigger surface area would work if they used a stylus.

Comment: true - I guess though not many people would have a stylus for their phones.

Comment: The angle of the finger would skew the resulting area. A lightly touched flat finger has a larger area then a hard push with a finger tip.

Comment: Thanks guys, both of these comments will have to make me rethink my idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can determine this with a very simple equation.

> Pressure = Force / Area

To solve this, you would need to know at least two of the variables. Suppose you can find the area from the phone's sensors. You would still need to know the pressure in order to calculate the force or in other words, how hard the user is pressing the screen.

Hope this helps you!